# Export to excel with python and xlwt using condition in column number

Tags: python, export-to-excel, xlwt

I make an export of a list to excel with Python (xlwt):

```
response = HttpResponse(mimetype="application/ms-excel")
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=MyList.xls'

wb = xlwt.Workbook()
ws = wb.add_sheet('my_list')

ws.write(0, 0, 'Country ID')
if var =='with_flag':
    ws.write(0, X, 'Country Flag')
ws.write(0, 1, 'Country Name')
```

If I export without flag the export passed nickel ;) , but the problem is when I choose to export with flag. I should respect the order of columns (1- `country_name`, 2- `country_flag` , 3-`country_id`). I know that Python doesn't support `++`. Is there any condition to make on `X` in my code to have the export in the specific order ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question right, you want something like this:

```
X = 1
if var =='with_flag':
    ws.write(0, X, 'Country Flag')
    X += 1
ws.write(0, X, 'Country Name')
```

Comment: it will work, but i post just 2/3 columns in the question. my export file will contains 20+ columns and i'm looking for elegant (minimized) way to do it not like your answer (adding an increment line for every column) . (+voteup for the answwer)

Comment: Regarding 20 columns. You would need to use a list, for example, to put your data in and iterate over this list and use the list index for the Excel column number.